# php switch case to change css class

Tags: php, jquery, session, switch-statement, case

I have a validation for my contact form that adds a red text font under required inputs. But what I really want is to add a red border-bottom to the bottom of the input to show it needs to be required. I have an already working php switch case but can not find the answer anywhere to add css classes to different cases. I hope someone knows more about this than I do.

Here is my php

```
    <?php
session_start();
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $humanErr = "";
    $Name = $Email = $Phone = $Human = "";

    $hasError = false;
    $sent = false;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $Name                = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Name'], ENT_QUOTES));
        $FName               = trim($_POST['FiancesName']);
        $Email               = trim($_POST['Email']);
        $DesiredWedDate      = trim($_POST['DesiredWedDate']);
        $WeddingSize         = trim($_POST['WeddingSize']);
        $Phone               = trim($_POST['Phone']);
        $IndoorCeremony      = trim($_POST['IndoorCeremony']);
        $OutdoorCeremony     = trim($_POST['OutdoorCeremony']);
        $AlcoholYes          = trim($_POST['AlcoholYes']);
        $AlcoholNo           = trim($_POST['AlcoholNo']);
        $Human               = trim($_POST['Human']);
        $Number              = 6;        







        $fieldsArray = array(
            'Name' => $Name,
            'Email' => $Email,
            'Phone' => $Phone,
            'Human' => $Human
        );

        $errorArray = array();

        foreach($fieldsArray as $key => $val) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'Name':
                    if(empty($val)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $nameErr = "Please enter your name.";
                    }
                case 'Name':
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", ($val))) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $nameErr = "The value must be alphanumeric."; 
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Phone':
                    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", ($val))) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $phoneErr = "Only numbers and white space allowed.";
                    }
                case 'Phone':
                    if(empty($val)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $phoneErr = "Phone is required.";
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Email':
                    if(!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $emailErr = "Email is required.";
                    } else {
                        $Email = filter_var($Email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Human':
                    if (!preg_match("/[^\d]?6[^\d]?/", ($val))) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $humanErr = "Not the right answer";
                    }
                case 'Human':
                    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", ($val))) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $humanErr = "Must be a number";
                    }
                case 'Human':
                    if(empty($val)) {
                        $hasError = true;
                        $humanErr = "Are you human?";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }


         //CHECK BOX WRITE UP
        if (isset($_POST['IndoorCeremony'])) {
        $checkBoxValue = "yes";
            //is checked
        } else {
            $checkBoxValue = "no";
            //is unchecked
        } 

        if (isset($_POST['OutdoorCeremony'])) {
        $checkBoxValue = "yes";
            //is checked
         } else {
            $checkBoxValue = "no";
            //is unchecked
        }

        if (isset($_POST['AlcoholYes'])) {
        $checkBoxValue = "yes";
            //is checked
        } else {
            $checkBoxValue = "no";
            //is unchecked
        }

        if (isset($_POST['AlcoholNo'])) {
        $checkBoxValue = "yes";
            //is checked
        } else {
            $checkBoxValue = "no";
            //is unchecked
        }


        //Validation Success!
        //Do form processing like email, database etc here
        if($hasError !== true) {
            $priority = $_POST['priority'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            //FOR STYLING EMAIL
            // $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
           //$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            //STYLING EMAIL
           /* $message = "<html>
                        <h1>
                        $Name
                        </h1>
                        <BR>
                        <h3>
                        $Email
                        <BR>Tel: $Phone
                        <BR>Company: $Compnay
                        <BR>Website: $Website
                        <BR>Subject: $Subjectmatter
                        <BR>Describe: $Describe
                        </h3>
                        <BR>
                        <BR>
                        <BR><h4>Web Design: $webdesign
                        <BR>Web Hosting: $webhosting
                        <BR>Wordpress Design: $wordpressdesign
                        <BR>Logo Design: $logodesign
                        <BR>Brochures: $brochures</h4>
                        <BR>
                        <BR>
                        <h4>
                        Other: $otherswitch
                        <BR>Describe: $OtherDescribe
                        </h4>
                        </html>";
                        */

            $formcontent=" From: $Name \n \n Fiance's Name: $FName \n \n Email: $Email \n \n Phone: $Phone \n \n Desired Wedding Date: $DesiredWedDate \n \n Wedding Size: $WeddingSize \n \n Describe: $Describe \n \n Indoor Ceremony: $IndoorCeremony \n \n Outdoor Ceremony: $OutdoorCeremony \n \n Alcohol Yes: $AlcoholYes \n \n Alcohol No $AlcoholNo \n \n Referral: $Referral \n ";
            $recipient = "Youremail@email.com";
            $subject = "Pre Book Wedding Contact Form";
            $mailheader = "From: $Email \r\n";
            mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader /*$message, $headers*/);
            header("Refresh:0; url=thanks.php");
            exit();       
        }
    }

?><!--END PHP-->
```

Here is my input form

```
<span class="input input--kaede">
                    <input name="FiancesName" class="input__field input__field--kaede" type="text" id="input-2" />
                    <label class="input__label input__label--kaede" for="input-2">
                        <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--kaede">Fiance's Name</span>
                    </label>
                </span>
```

The css I want to add
I called it

```
.under_text_error {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

that should hopefully give someone enough to go off of. I appreciate any possible help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
 <?php 
         if(!empty($nameErr)) 
         { 
   ?>
             <div class="under_text_error"> 
                <?php echo $nameErr ?>
             </div>
   <?php 
         } 
   ?>
```

Comment: okay that works, but the problem is when i submit. The red underline styas and the input inside disappears.

Comment: yes no problem. I added that code between the span class and the input name. Now when i hit submit, the red underline shows up. When I fill the info in and resubmit the line still stays and the inputed information disappears.

Comment: dont give the input in this span class..As per our condition,it doesnt display this span ,if there is no error.Give that error message only in this class

Comment: above i reposted what I tried with your code. not exactly sure if im doing it right (obviously not).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
   <span class="input input--kaede <?php echo $FnameErr ?>"> 
<?php 
if(!empty($FnameErr)) 
{ 
?> 
<div class="under_text_error"> 

</div> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
<input name="FName" class="input__field input__field--kaede " type="text" id="input-2"  value="<?php echo (isset($FName) ? $FName : ""); ?>"/> 
<label class="input__label input__label--kaede " for="input-2"> 
<span class="input__label-content input__label-content--kaede ">Fiance's Name</span> 
</label> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the error class if the field has an error

Something like:

```
<input class="input__field input__field--kaede <?=isset($nameErr)? 'under_text_error':''?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is what I tried.

```
<span class="input input--kaede <?php echo $nameErr ?>">
                    <?php
                        if(!empty($nameErr))
                        {
                    ?>
                        <div class="under_text_error">

                        </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    <input name="Name" class="input__field input__field--kaede " type="text" id="input-2" />
                    <label class="input__label input__label--kaede " for="input-2" value="<?php echo (isset($Name) ? $Name : ""); ?>">
                        <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--kaede ">Fiance's Name</span>
                    </label>
                </span>
```

What this ends up doing is putting the red line on the input and when i fill it in and submit it disappears like its suppose to. The problem now is that the input information (what you type in disappears) it doesn't keep it.

Comment: can u put the screenshot of the output

Answer (score 0):

Here is before you fill or submit
[image]

Ignore the top red. I was just testing other options. but as you can see the line works here after submit and no answer.
[image]

Here is a shot of filling answer in. once submitted it looks like image 1, but blank.
[image]

Here is what it looks like last after submit. So it forgets
[image]

Comment: did you check it the way i posted recently>

Comment: yes i did. I am getting the same thing. Is this just to complicated to do? should i be trying something else?

Comment: nops..dont give up..is your current php code the same as posted in  your question?

Comment: I guess this line `$Name = $Email = $Phone = $Human = "";` is resetting your value to null..why do you need that line?

Comment: i was told i needed it. but i just tried to delete it and still same. There is more php below what I put but thats to email. I can add it so you can see

Comment: then its not required..may be you'll have to assign the value of $name to a session variable so that it doesnt become null

Comment: how would i go about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135210/discussion-between-affaz-and-digital-jedi-3).